# How to to delete multiple items not in a given array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this code:

```
delIndex = []
for a in range(0, 10):
    if a not in found_index and len(found_index) > 0:
        delIndex.append(a)
for index in sorted(delIndex, reverse=True):
    del faces[index]
```

This code delete items who are not in the array `found_index`
Is there a way simplify the code by using a method that do this job or another thing?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. you ask: "Is there a way simplify by using a method that do this job or another thing?" What is "another thing" in this context? What part of the above code exactly are you trying to simplify? Also, where is the `faces` dict coming from? What is "this job"?

Comment: why the "numpy" tag ?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the array is unique? If you want to remove `1` from `[1,2,3,1]`, what do you expect?

Comment: Check these links :
[link 1](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/03/25/Deleting-multiple-elements-of-a-list/)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36268815/9400024) 
they might help you to get info!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a **[mcve]**, as your question is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the code to:

```
delIndex = sorted([a for a in range(0, 10) if a not in found_index], reverse=True)  
for index in delIndex:
    del faces[index]
```

If you update your answer with more details and samples of the list `faces` and `found_index` (e.g. is it unique, does it contain duplicates), and why you do a revers-sort, I may update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what faces is so I explain only how to remove elements by a difference of two sets of elements. In your case `found_index` and `[a for a in range(0, 10)]` . Use `set` built in in python, and the difference methods - [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
values_to_remove = set([a for a in range(0, 10)])
found_index = set(found_index)
new_itemS = found_index.difference(values_to_remove)
# you can write also new_itemS = found_index - values_to_remove     new set with elements in found_index but not in values_to_remove
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that you want to filter out all elements from a list, which are contained in a second list:

```
[element for element in faces if element not in found_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set for that

**Try like this:-**

```
a = [6,8,10] #to be deleted
b = list(range(11)) #compare list
ls= set(b) ^ set(a)
print(ls)#your output
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you are looking for [How to remove specific element in an array using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118276/how-to-remove-specific-element-in-an-array-using-python).

Let me know if this is what you are looking for. Alternatively provide us a sample of input and output so we can play with your code.

**Update**: Adding sample of code.

Sample of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

mainArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arrayRemove = [1, 3, 6]

mainArray = [e for e in mainArray if e not in arrayRemove]
print(mainArray)
```

Comment: this belongs to a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Hello @brunodesthuilliers,

You know before voting down a new user that it is trying to assist for free his time it would better to teach how this forum works. Alternatively you end up pushing people out of spending their time to assist. (Keep that in mind for the next user that you will do the same)

Comment: Since it is documented better provide a link in case that someone does not know where to read it. On top of that learn how to train to create better developers instead of train how to be wrong.