# remove some string from a text file

Tags: python-3.7

I have a text file and I want to remove a part of text using Python 3.7.

Example:

```
helloooooooooooooo ### 122
How Are uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu?
GigaEthernet              0          1          0
GigaEthernet              1           2          0
GigaEthernet               2         1            3 
helloooooooooooooo ### 122
helloooooooooooooo ### 122
```

i want the text file change to:

```
GigaEthernet              0          1          0
GigaEthernet              1           2          0
GigaEthernet               2         1            3
```

It maybe "FastEthernet" instead of GigaEthernet so we should consider "Ethernet" as a key word).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you a complete solution, I'll help on how to approach this kind of problem. 
What do you have? A file.
What do you want? A modified file.

- First, you need to load in the file as a data structure that you can work with, see: [How to read a text file into a list or an array with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python)
- Second, you need to remove some lines, see: [How to remove specific element in an array using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118276/how-to-remove-specific-element-in-an-array-using-python)
- Third, you need to save the changes to a file, see: [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

I hope that this helps.